# less css loop matrix

Tags: css, less

I have a list of strings as such in LESS: `@flag-codes: "Albania" "al", "United States" "us", ...`; I created a loop in LESS which I have achieved by using:

```
.flag-classes(@flags; @index: 1) when (@index <= length(@flag-codes)) {

    @flag: extract(@flags, @index);

    @name:  extract(@flag, 1);
    @code: e(extract(@flag, 2));


    // X Y

    .flag-@{code} {
        background-position: (24 * mod(@index, 8)) mod(@index, 16);
    }

    .flag-classes(@flags; (@index + 1));
}


.flag-classes(@flag-codes);
```

As you can see I am also trying to generate a `background-position` property which will have the values based on the loop index, but that only on the `x` axis.

The image used is a `PNG` sprite that has a collection of sprites organised in a matrix (8 columns and 16 rows).

I have managed to figure out how to set the `x` property which will always have `@index % 8`, but on the `y` axis it will have to start from 1 to 16 and keep the 1 for 8 times (as many columns as we have) and after each 8 increase with a unit.

Is something as described above possible to do, and if so how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple:

```
.flag-@{code} {
    @columns: 8;
    @x: (24 * mod(@index, @columns));
    @y: floor((@index / @columns + 1));
    background-position: @x @y;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make the index start from 0 in the calculations but not in the loop?

Comment: Actually `@index - 1` will do :)

Comment: Correction: `@index - 1` will do for the `x` axis, but on the `y` axis only works up to the `first row - 1` ...

Comment: I intentionally added `1` to `y` since you mentioned "y axis it will have to start from 1 to 16". If you actually need "0 to 15" instead then it simply would be `@y: floor((@index / @columns));`

Comment: that is what I tried, but the 8th, 16th, etc. (8nth) already get's the next index value, so the 8th for instance instead of still being 0 it is 1.

Comment: So what values for x and y are supposed to be there in the end? If it's `[0 ... n]` for both x and y (I'd expect the first sprite to be at `0, 0`) then it's actually would make sense to start the loop with `index = 0` (and use `extract(@flags, (@index + 1));` for `flag` extraction) - that way it will be more compact. Either way you still can get *any* `y` offset pattern by addind/substracting `1` before or after division (or *both* - i.e. it's four possible patterns in total).

Comment: The values would be as you'd expect (start from `0 0` and move `24 * @index 0` for as many times as columns I have and then move one row down `0 floor((@index / @columns))` etc.).

Comment: Your suggestions with the index works perfectly now :) thanks